# Ogre Tutorial project compiles but no render window displayed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installation, ogre

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question. I generally resort to Stackoverflow only when there seems to be no other recourse to my problem, and indeed I've spent well over two days wrangling over the installation and set up of Ogre3D.

I'm running a Windows 7 64 bit system and using Visual Studio 2010 to compile the Ogre libraries. I have a fair bit of programming experience.

The problem is pretty aptly summed up by the title, but to give a little more detail, I've managed to get to the point of compiling the source code of the Tutorial Application provided on the Ogre website:

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application

I've gone through every inch of it, as well as the pages leading up to it, and have checked off everything. I am certain the instructions have been followed to the letter.

The problem is, the code seems to compile fine but the RENDER WINDOW won't display no matter what I try to do.

When I try to "Start Debugging" all that happens is that an application process is started which runs in the background with no GUI initializing. I've tried this in both Debug and Release mode and it seems to make no visible difference except that the Release mode compiles and executes faster.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT : I've looked at the error log in the Ogre directory and found no evidence of any errors or failure in installation. So that narrows it down somewhat.

EDIT 2 : spacegaier has been so kind as to help me out, and suggested that I delete ogre.cfg in order to allow it to be recreated. He also thinks that it could be perhaps the settings used on the website simply do not work for my machine.

The code simply does not seem to reach the point where the configuration display is launched, even though the source code compiles successfully.

EDIT 3:
Debug log:

'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\Ogre_Project.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\OgreMain_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\OIS_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput8.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\OgreOverlay_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
Creating resource group General
Creating resource group Internal
Creating resource group Autodetect
SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Material
Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type EmbeddedZip registered.
DDS codec registering
FreeImage version: 3.15.3
This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,3fr,arw,bay,bmq,cap,cine,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,drf,dsc,dng,erf,fff,ia,iiq,k25,kc2,kdc,mdc,mef,mos,mrw,nef,nrw,orf,pef,ptx,pxn,qtk,raf,raw,rdc,rw2,rwl,rwz,sr2,srf,srw,sti
Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
Loading library .\RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded  'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d8thk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\D3DX9_43.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
Installing plugin: D3D9 RenderSystem
D3D9 : Direct3D9 Rendering Subsystem created.
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvspcap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x23f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
D3D9: Driver Detection Starts
D3D9: Driver Detection Ends
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\RenderSystem_Direct3D11_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\RenderSystem_Direct3D11_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\D3DCompiler_43.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Installing plugin: D3D11 RenderSystem
D3D11 : Direct3D11 Rendering Subsystem created.
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgidebug.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvwgf2um.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2f4c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
D3D11: Driver Detection Starts
D3D11: Driver Detection Ends
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\RenderSystem_GL_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\RenderSystem_GL_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
Installing plugin: GL RenderSystem
OpenGL Rendering Subsystem created.
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2f34) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Ogre_Project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winsta.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2598) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x33e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xf1c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\Plugin_ParticleFX_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\Plugin_ParticleFX_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Installing plugin: ParticleFX
Particle Emitter Type 'Point' registered
Particle Emitter Type 'Box' registered
Particle Emitter Type 'Ellipsoid' registered
Particle Emitter Type 'Cylinder' registered
Particle Emitter Type 'Ring' registered
Particle Emitter Type 'HollowEllipsoid' registered
Particle Affector Type 'LinearForce' registered
Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader' registered
Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader2' registered
Particle Affector Type 'ColourImage' registered
Particle Affector Type 'ColourInterpolator' registered
Particle Affector Type 'Scaler' registered
Particle Affector Type 'Rotator' registered
Particle Affector Type 'DirectionRandomiser' registered
Particle Affector Type 'DeflectorPlane' registered
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\Plugin_BSPSceneManager_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\Plugin_BSPSceneManager_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Installing plugin: BSP Scene Manager
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\Plugin_CgProgramManager_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\Plugin_CgProgramManager_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\cg.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Installing plugin: Cg Program Manager
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\Plugin_PCZSceneManager_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded    'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\Plugin_PCZSceneManager_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Installing plugin: Portal Connected Zone Scene Manager
PCZone Factory Type 'ZoneType_Default' registered
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\Plugin_OctreeZone_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\Plugin_OctreeZone_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Installing plugin: Octree Zone Factory
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library .\Plugin_OctreeSceneManager_d
'Ogre_Project.exe': Loaded   'C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\bin\debug\Plugin_OctreeSceneManager_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Installing plugin: Octree Scene Manager
Plugin successfully installed
*-*-* OGRE Initialising
*-*-* Version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x22f8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3010) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

EDIT 4:

Alright, problem solved. Switched my environment to Visual Studio 2013 and used the same settings as well as the pre - built binaries made by Lothar from here: ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=79550&start=25 The man deserves an award.

Comment: Do you see an Ogre3D display config dialog appearing? If not, remove the ogre.cfg file for it to be displayed during the next application run. It could be that the values listed on the tutorial page simply do not work for your machine.

Cross post: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=83502&p=518079#p518075

Comment: Oh my apologies, I thought cross posting was restricted to different forums on the Ogre3D webpage itself!

Comment: Did not consider that it extended to other forums altogether. Will refrain from it in the future.

Comment: Did you try, what I proposed? What was the result? Any change in application's behavior?

Comment: I've been searching the Ogre SDK directory but there doesn't seem to be a Ogre.cfg anywhere! 
Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: Nevermind, found it. Testing results.

Comment: Okay, deleted ogre.cfg and ogre_d.cfg, tried compiling and running the application both through Visual studio and externally. 
Does not seem to have any effect. =( 
Also of note, the ogre.cfg files do not seem to be recreated after running the application.

Comment: The *ogre.cfg* from the SDK should not play a role, but either the one directly in your application folder (if you put one there) or in your user home directory would. Also make sure to use the latest [Ogre Tutorial Framework](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Ogre%20Wiki%20Tutorial%20Framework) that also matches your Ogre version. I saw that there was a bad old link in the tutorial you mentioned and I just fixed that.

Comment: I am using the Tutorial Framework version appropriate for Ogre 1.9. And isn't the user home directory the folder assigned to OGRE_HOME?
Which is indeed the SDK folder?
I am sorry for this confusion.

Comment: And there is no ogre.cfg file in my application folder. Confirmed this.

Comment: Just in case, I downloaded the new set of Framework files and rebuilt them. Did not make a difference.

Comment: No, your user home directory on Windows is *C:\users\<user_name>*, where as OGRE_HOME is completely arbitrary. Did you try to debug your application, because I see *mRoot->showConfigDialog()* in the tutorial framework code, so you should see that dialog. As it does not appear I assume that you are never reaching that line for some reason. The debugger will know more.

Comment: Alright I am officially confused. =(
The only ogre.cfg that I can find is in the path:
C:\Users\Nightmask3\Cworkspace\OgreSDK\Samples\Browser
And deleting it had no effect. 
Also tried compiling in debug mode, and it had no effect.
Is there some log from the debugger I should be including?

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint in the debug mode and then check where your application is existing / crashing. For how to debug ask Google.

Comment: Alright, problem solved. Switched my environment to Visual Studio 2013 and used the same settings as well as the pre - built binaries made by Lothar from here:
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=79550&start=25
The man deserves an award.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer for clarity.

I've seen multiple occurrences of this problem during my search for an answer, which makes me think it might be something that happens with some regularity. If anyone else runs into a similar situation, here's how I fixed it:

1) The problem seems to have been caused by something tied to Visual Studio 2010, but I'm not sure if it was specific to my environment, or an error in the Project Settings or some other issue like that. I triple checked the settings so I'm fairly confident it may be linked to VS 2010, on my machine at least.

2) I am running a Windows 7 64 bit system which is another potential cause for the problem. I was unsure of whether or not I had to use the 64 bit prebuilt binaries provided on the website or just the 32 bit version. It stood to sense that I should use the stable 1.9 32 bit version which is what I did with this installation, and it did not work at all. If you have a 64 bit system, this might be the answer you were looking for.

2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 if you don't already have it. It is also the only IDE which is currently recognized by the Unreal Engine 4, so at the very least it provides a unified work environment.

3) Download the prebuilt binaries of Ogre v1.9 so kindly compiled by a user called Lothar on the Ogre3D forums. These are meant to be used on a 64 bit system and are expressly compiled for VS2013, so I doubt they'll work on any other configuration.

http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=79550&p=504669&hilit=2013#p504699

4) Use the guide provided on the Ogre3D site to configure your project environment in VS 2013 as it needs to be to work with Ogre.

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Installing+the+Ogre+SDK

5) Download the Tutorial Framework files and include them in your project.

6) Set your target machine type from 'x86' to 'x64' in Visual Studio.

7) Compile and run, lo and behold! The application executes successfully. (hopefully)

Hope this is of some use to someone!
  Thanks to spacegaier for his time in helping me out.